# How to distribute and fit h2o model by group in sparklyr

Tags: h2o, sparklyr

I would like to fit a model by group in h2o using some type of distributed apply function.

I tried the following but it doesn't work. Probably due to the fact I cannot pipe the sc object through.

```
df%>%
  spark_apply(function(e)
        h2o.coxph(x = predictors,
                       event_column = "event",
                       stop_column = "time_to_next",
                       training_frame = as_h2o_frame(sc, e, strict_version_check = FALSE))      
  group_by = "id"
  )
```

I receive a pretty generic spark error like this:

```
error : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 23.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 23.0 :
```

Comment: Are you using the rsparkling package?  Can you make a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can return an entire H2OCoxPH model from `sparklyr::spark_apply()`: Errors are `no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector` if you set the `fetch_result_as_sdf` argument to `FALSE` and `cannot coerce class ‘structure("H2OCoxPHModel", package = "h2o")’ to a data.frame` if set to `TRUE`.

But if you can make your own vector or dataframe from the relevant parts of the model, I think you can do it.

Here I'll use a sample Cox Proportional Hazards file from [H2O Docs Cox Proportional Hazards (CoxPH)](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/coxph.html) and I'll use `group_by = "surgery"`.

```
heart_hf <- h2o::h2o.importFile("http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/coxph_test/heart.csv")

##### Convert to Spark DataFrame since I assume that is the use case
heart_sf <- sparklyr::copy_to(sc, heart_hf %>% as.data.frame())

##### Use sparklyr::spark_apply() on Spark DataFrame to "distribute and fit h2o model by group"
sparklyr::spark_apply(
    x = heart_sf,
    f = function(x) {
        h2o::h2o.init()
        
        heart_coxph <- h2o::h2o.coxph(x = c("age", "year"),
                                      event_column = "event",
                                      start_column = "start",
                                      stop_column = "stop",
                                      ties = "breslow",
                                      training_frame = h2o::as.h2o(x, strict_version_check = FALSE))
        
        return(data.frame(conc = heart_coxph@model$model_summary$concordance))
    },
    columns = list(surgery = "integer", conc = "numeric"),
    group_by = c("surgery"))
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
  surgery  conc
    <int> <dbl>
1       1 0.588
2       0 0.614
```